# Version Number Management - how do you do it?

Tags: java, maven, versioning

I have a Maven project that needs to be versioned. I have chosen to use the `versions-maven-plugin` as my versioning plugin but am unsure if that's the best option.

I have read the documentation that such plugin actually **modifies the POM** and I don't really like that approach. I have worked on projects where they had separate `build.properties` file that got modified manually.

What I want to achieve is to have my CI **generating the artifact for me ready to be deployed and update the version number** automatically.

So, any suggestions? How have **you** done before?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

I'd get the version number from the one source that matters: that's the source code management system (Subverson, Mercurial, or Git), not Maven.

I'd say that Maven might be out of synch unless your Maven plug-in is getting it from SCM.

Answer (score 2):

Use the Release Plugin. You want to perform automatic deployment and batch release. The Versions Plugin is designed for something else.

Answer (score 1):

We have found [MAVEN-RELEASE-PLUGIN](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-release-plugin/) super useful and can not imagine releasing and managing version with it.